# Toggle unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, list, toggle

I have a long unordered list that must be cut down and each time 10 items must be visible in visible area and by clicking one arrow button the next 10 items show up. something like [this image](http://s4.picofile.com/file/7924806020/list.jpg).

each column HTML code is like this:

```
<li class="linkcat"><h2>Main Title</h2>
    <ul class="xoxo blogroll">
     <li><a href="#">Title 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Title 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Title 3</a></li>
     ...
     <li><a href="#">Title 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Better question: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check the answer but you may find better plugins for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/vbgWh/1/) (It depends on `css`, so make sure you use it properly), also, you may find better plugins for this and this may not best but just a way to overcome my boringness because I was free.

```
$(function(){
    var visible_items = 10, vi = visible_items;
    $('li.linkcat ul li, #prev, #next').hide();
    $('li.linkcat ul li').each(function(i){
        if(i < vi) $(this).addClass('visible').show();
        if(i > vi) {
            $('#next').show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#next').click(function(){
        var lastLi = $('li.visible:last');
        if(lastLi.next('li').length){
            $('li.linkcat ul li.visible').removeClass('visible').hide();
            for(var ind=(lastLi.index()+1), i = ind; i < (ind+vi); i++){
                $('li.linkcat ul li').eq(i).show().addClass('visible');
            }
            $('#prev').show();
            if(!$('li.linkcat ul li').eq(lastLi.index()+(vi*2)).length){
                $('#next').hide();
            }
        }
    });

    $('#prev').click(function(){
        var firstLi = $('li.visible:first');
        if(firstLi.prev('li').length){
            $('li.linkcat ul li.visible').removeClass('visible').hide();
            for(var ind=(firstLi.index()-1), i = ind; i > (ind-vi); i--){
                $('li.linkcat ul li').eq(i).show().addClass('visible');
            }
            $('#next').show();
            if($('li.linkcat ul li').eq((vi-1)).is(':visible')) {
                $('#prev').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```